# Is there a way to return variables from R function when terminated by hand?

Tags: r, function, return

So I have evolutionary algorithm, which takes some time to run. I have written it as a function and wrap it in package, and now I am facing the issue with early stopping. Is there a way to return current variables even if you terminate the function before completion?

I am looking for something like return on error, like when you running script on stoppage the current variables remain in environment. Is that possible in R?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an *Exit handler* with `on.exit` defined in your function. A simple usage, where I terminate the function with ctrl-c is:

```
fun  <- function() {
  on.exit(return(i))
  i <- 0
  repeat {
    i  <- i + 1
    Sys.sleep(1)
  }
}

z <- fun()
#^C
z
#[1] 3
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd not pack the code into a function in your case.
Still, if that's needed I found a solution that matches what I studied at datacamp:

https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2004-February/046366.html

By default, when a function throw an error it does not return anything other than the error message. So you need to assign it's working variables into the global enviorement.

> ...
>   You can do one of the following:
>
> 2. Use assign and explicitly assign it in the global  environment rather than the local environment of the function:     plotsinx <-
>      function(x) { 
>        assign("sinx",sin(x),.GlobalEnv)
>        plot(sinx)
>      }
> 3. Use <<- as in:    plotsinx <- function(x) { 
>        sinx <<- sin(x)
>        plot(sinx)
>      } If you use this one be sure that you don't nest the  definition of plotsinx in another function since it actually searches through the
>      environments of the definition's parents.
>
> ...

Look at the help of:

> ?"<<-"
>
> ?assign

Comment: I am familiar with those operators, but then my global will be polluted. Perhaps if on error I can execute the function that removes those variables from global env? And since the program has a lot of params, overwriting something in global env would be big issue.